# Switch case based on flag condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, switch-statement

I have 3 variables to store my 3 checkboxes status as follow:

```
var selectA =$('#checkbox-v-6a').is(':checked');
var selectB =$('#checkbox-v-6b').is(':checked');
var selectC =$('#checkbox-v-6c').is(':checked');
```

I want to send a variable to a python function based on the checkboxes status, such as if all checkboxes are checked, selection = "all"; if only checkbox A and B is selected, selection="AB"; if only checkbox C is selected, selection="C". I know that var `selectA`, `selectB` and `selectC` will give me `true` and `false` but I'm not sure how to do a switch case for this?

Or do I use `if-else`?

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                    <legend>Select Pill Types</legend>
                    <input name="checkbox-v-6a" id="checkbox-v-6a" type="checkbox" class="pillselect" value="a">
                    <label for="checkbox-v-6a">Multivitamins</label>
                    <input name="checkbox-v-6b" id="checkbox-v-6b" type="checkbox" class="pillselect" value="b">
                    <label for="checkbox-v-6b">Calcium</label>
                    <input name="checkbox-v-6c" id="checkbox-v-6c" type="checkbox" class="pillselect" value="c">
                    <label for="checkbox-v-6c">Omega-3</label>
                </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each) like,

```
var selection=[];
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
   selection.push(this.id);
});
alert('Checked id: '+selection.join(', '));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/A8TuU/)

If you want to set `values` in `array` then try this,

```
var selection=[];
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
   selection.push(this.value);
});
alert('Checked id: '+selection.join(', '));
```

[Update value demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/A8TuU/1/)

Comment: how about if i want to get the value instead? i've updated my question with the HTML code. i tried `selection.push(this.val);` but it doesnt work.

Comment: Use `this.value` like `selection.push(this.value);` See my `updated demo` http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/A8TuU/1/

Comment: `join()` need a `parameter string` to `concat` try this `selection.join('')`